# http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors

I'm receiving the message 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' when making a request via an Angular application (version 8.1.2).
Thank you in advance for everyone's attention.
I will put my CorsFilter handling classes below.
In this AppConfig class I am trying to treat cors globally and not within controllers using @CrossOrigin(origins = "*") for example.

```
import java.time.Duration;

import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {

        return builder
                .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(240000)) //2m
                .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(240000))  //2m
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```